# How to select data from database with two tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables named at `Exams`, `Payments`.

In this `Exams` table I stored all exam details on my college

```
| id | examid | fees |
----------------------
|  1 | exam01 | 1000 |
|  2 | exam02 | 3000 |
|  3 | exam03 | 2500 |
```

In this `Payments` table i stored all payments details from my students

```
| id | examid | uname | fees |
------------------------------
|  1 | exam01 | kumar | 1000 |
|  2 | exam02 | kumar | 3000 |
|  3 | exam01 | johny | 1000 |
|  4 | exam03 | johny | 2500 |
```

Now i need to select all non-payable exams from kumar user 
 Like this

```
| id | examid | fees |
----------------------
|  3 | exam03 | 2500 |
```

I tried Joins, Unions queries but I dont know how to use this.
is this any solution for my issue

Comment: Edit. your question and show your attempts.

Comment: Please don't tag spam. Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? PHPMyAdmin is an web based IDE for MySQL, but what are you asking about that? What does the question have to do with PHP at all? Are you looking for a solution that's in PHP not SQL? [Edit] your question and tag **properly** please.

Comment: Exactly how does your example relate to the other tables? Is it just a list of exams that user "kumar" has not paid for?

Comment: You mean to want to know which exams "Kumar" is not registered for? (Or hasn't paid for? It's unclear what the data actually represents)

Comment: Have you got a defined FK from `Payments` to `Exams` or are you expecting to match it on the `examid` text?

Comment: I store all exams on `Exams` Table. and I store all payment details on `Payments` table. I need to know which exams kumar user not registered(not paid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    e.Id,
    e.ExamId,
    e.Fees
FROM 
    Exams AS e
    LEFT JOIN Payments AS p ON p.ExamId = e.ExamId
        AND p.uname = 'kumar'
WHERE
    p.Id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks its works.I tried the Left Join methods but i forget to add where statement 

This is worked for me
`SELECT
    e.Id,
    e.ExamId,
    e.Fees
FROM 
    Exams AS e
    LEFT JOIN Payments AS p ON p.examid = e.examid
        AND p.uname = 'kumar'
WHERE
    p.Id IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

you can use following query

```
select * 
from Exams 
  where id not in
   (select Exams.id
   from 
   (select * from Payments where uname = 'kumar') t join Exams on t.examid = Exams.examid)
```